# Principal direction in a binary image

Tags: matlab, angle, pca

As shown in image, there is a binary polygonal image. I want to find the principal direction in the image with respect to X-axis. I have shown the principal direction and X-axis with blue line. This can be done using PCA but my problem is such a small rectangle will have around 1000 pixels and I have to find Principal directions for around 100 polygons (polygon can be of arbitrary shape).

One approach that I have thought is:
Project that rectangle onto a line which is oriented at degrees at an interval (say) 5 degrees. The projection which has the maximum variance is the desired projection axis, and thus that is the desired angle. But this also falls under a greedy approach and thus will take time. Is there a smarter approach?

Also, if anybody could explain the exact procedure to do this using PCA, it would be helpful. I know the steps:
1. Take the covariance matrix.
2. Get the top eigenvector corresponding to largest eigenvalue -> that will be the principal direction.

But I am confused in the following statement which I often read everywhere:

A column vector: `[0.5 0.5]` is the first principal component and it gives the direction of the maximum variance. So can do I exactly calculate the angle by which I should rotate the data so that it will become parallel to X-axis.

[image]

Comment: what about finding the moment of inertia (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_moment_of_area#Any_cross_section_defined_as_polygon )  and from that you'll get it's principle directions by calculating its eigenvectors

Comment: I don't really see why you can't just use PCA, you have 1000 pixels, that is 1000, 2d vectors. Computing the covariance matrix of that is trivial, and finding the eigen values and eigenvectors should be immediate. Is there a specific reason why you're overthinking this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compute the eigenvector associated with the highest eigen value. Call that v. Normalize v. v = v/norm(v);

Compute angle between that and the horizontal direction: angle=acos(sum(v.*[1,0]))

Rotate by -angle, transformation matrix T = [cos(-angle) -sin(-angle); sin(-angle) cos(-angle)], multiply all points by that matrix. Do that for all polygons.